# bytearray: How to split hexadecimal digits and preserve type

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, hex

This does not give the expected result:

```
import base64

k = 'EQAAAE4kAARA'
l = bytearray(base64.b64decode(k))
m = l.hex()
m
```

Output:

```
'110000004e24000440'
```

I intend to split the hexadecimal string at the 8th digit, combine it, flip it (MSB) and convert to decimal:

```
n = [d for d in str(n)]
o = "".join(n[:7])
p = int(o)
p = bytearray(p)
q = int.from_bytes(p, byteorder='little')
q
```

Output:

```
0
```

I am supposed to get 17 as the decimal conversion from 11000000 hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> int.from_bytes(binascii.unhexlify('11000000'), 'little')
17
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio! For some reason, it does not work for me. Please see the error:NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4109c6b20952> in <module>()
     11 #z = int.from_bytes(y, byteorder='big')
     12 #z= int.from_bytes(p, byteorder='little')
---> 13 z= int.from_bytes(binascii.unhexlify(o), 'little')
     14 z

NameError: name 'binascii' is not defined

Comment: Did you try importing it?

Comment: Thank you very much! My bad :-)